# How to generate sourceMap file for css or scss?

Tags: css, sass, source-maps

Can't find out the way to make source map for css. Can anybody give a hint?

Comment: you can set the source map option to true.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly this option is?

Comment: No, because you don't tell us what you are using to create CSS from SCSS.

Comment: @cloned I have a React project and every component has css module, scss module and a source map (name.module.css.map). I don't understand how the source map is generated. I would be very glad if you help me to understand how it works, may be I don't know what else you need to know

Comment: If you search for `create sourcemap css react` do you get any useful results? What didn't work for the results you got for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers for SASS/LESS will make a sourceMap for you while compiling your code. If they didn't it's probably a setting.

You can read some more here https://cssdeck.com/blog/how-to-create-css-map-file/

Comment: Thanks, I tried to follow these instructions bus it always showed that scss is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a few ways to generate `fileName.css.map` or `fileName.scss.map` or anything you want.

First create a file `optionalName.css`.

**1)** Install sass: `npm install -g sass`.

The pattern looks like this: `sass input.css output.css`.

Then go to your terminal and type `sass optionalName.css optionalName.css`.

Sometimes you need to specify path to your file like:

`sass src/css/example.css src/css/example.css`

And you see `optionalName.css.map` file is generated in your folder.

You can also convert `scss` to `css` by running `sass optionalName.scss:optionalName.css`.

**2)** Go to VS Code and install **Live Sass Compiler** extension. When it's installed you'll see a **Watch Sass** button in the blue bar below. Just open a **SCSS** file you need, say, `styles.scss`, and press the **Watch Sass** button. Right after that all necessary files are generated in your folder:

```
styles.css
styles.css.map
styles.scss
```